# Show Div only when scrolled and element available in a dynamic list

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, addeventlistener, scrollspy

I have a list of elements, and the length is dynamic it can be a value upto 1000.

what i am doing now is that i loop through the list and create a div for every element which in turn **increases my DOM size**.
So, I want to load say 5 div(if the list size is >=5) and load the rest when the user scrolls. Assume 5 div's cover the entire page.
can someone hint me or show me a way on how to do it without jquery(as jquery bundle size is huge )

**Sample of what i was trying to do**

```
 data = list/json of number e.g data =[1,2,3,4,5,.....]
    
    const finalResponse = () =>
    data.map(idx: number): React.ReactElement => {
                        return (<div>sample idx</div>);})
    
    main()
    {return <>{finalResponse()}</>}
```

**Final out to look something like this in my case:**

```
<>
<div>sample 1</div>
<div>sample 2</div>
<div>sample 3</div>
<div>sample 4</div>
<div>sample 5</div>
<div>sample 6</div>
<div>sample 7</div>
<div>sample 8</div> and so on
</>
```

**what i want is**

```
  <>
    <div>sample 1</div>
    <div>sample 2</div>
    <div>sample 3</div>
    <div>sample 4</div>
    <div>sample 5</div>
    </>
and add the rest when scrolled
```

Comment: For clarification: You want to display upto 1000 div elements a) 5 at a time or b) 5 new elements at a time with older elements remaining on screen?

Comment: 5 new elements at a time with older elements remaining on screen

Comment: I removed the Lighthouse tag as this does not appear to be related to Google Lighthouse in any way and that is what the tag is for, I hope you don't mind. I hope someone can answer this for you!

Answer (score 0):

resolved this by adding an event listener on scroll.

on scroll, the function sets the state to true

and i do something like

```
const finalResponse = (start,end) =>
   data.slice(start,end+1)map(idx: number): React.ReactElement => {
                       return (<div>sample idx</div>);})

   main()
   {return <>{finalResponse(0,5)}
{finalResponse(6,data.length)}
</>}
```